# Independence of events that are independent to each other.

Tags: probability

Assuming that events A and B are both independent events, would A and `not B` be independent? would `not B` and `not A` be independent? I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then also $A$ and $B^c$ are independent as well as $A^c$ and $B^c$. For instance, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then we know that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. But then
$$
P(A)=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A)P(B)
$$
by [the law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), and hence
$$
P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)[1-P(B)]=P(A)P(B^c).
$$
A similar argument can be used to show that $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent.